# How To Add Event In Array Of Google Maps Polygon. Only Some of Them Have the Event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, google-maps-api-3, polygon

All. I'm developing dashboard application which uses google maps API. I'm trying to render many google.maps.Polygon in a map.
Once it loads polygon data from AJAX request, I created some polygons, and I store them in array. For each loop of creating polygon, 
I added google maps event to every polygon (mouseover, mouseout, and click event). It succesfully rendered all polygon on the map. But 
not all polygon has event, just some of them. Would you like to give me some solutions of this problem?

Here is the part of code

```
function big_loadMapCells() {

    var serviceUrl = './Services/example';

    var currentIdx = 0;
    var pagingCount = 5000;

    while (currentIdx < totalCount) {
        // send ajax
        Ext.Ajax.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: serviceUrl + '?start=' + currentIdx + '&limit=' + pagingCount,
            timeout: 300000,
            success: function (c) {
                var jsonObj = Ext.JSON.decode(c.responseText);
                if (jsonObj) {
                    big_createCellsFromJSON(jsonObj);
                }
            }
        });
        currentIdx += pagingCount;
    }
}

function big_createCellsFromJSON(jsonObj) {
    // looping for creating polygon
    for (var a = 0; a < jsonObj.items.length; a++) {
        var cellJson = jsonObj.items[a];

        var data = {
            lacCi: cellJson.LACCI
            tech: cellJson.TECH,
            periodType: cellJson.PERIOD_TIME,
            time: cellJson.DATETIME_ID,
            region: cellJson.REGION,
            latitude: cellJson.LATITUDE,
            longitude: cellJson.LONGITUDE,
            node: cellJson.NODE,
            siteName: cellJson.SITE,
            kpi: cellJson.KPI,
            cellName: cellJson.CELL_NAME,
            azimuth: cellJson.AZIMUTH,
            beamWidth: width,
            beamConst: radius,
            color: cellJson.COLOR
        };

        var myCell = big_createCellPolygon(data);
        big_arrCells.push(myCell);
    }
}

function big_createCellPolygon(data) {
    // create polygon using my own javascript, CELL object
    var myCell = new CELL();

    myCell.setOptions({
        paths: myCell.pts,
        strokeColor: myCell.color,
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor: myCell.color,
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        map: big_map
    });

    function addCellEvent(myCell) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(myCell, 'mouseover', function () {
            this.setOptions({
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillOpacity: 0.7
            });
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myCell, 'mouseout', function () {
            this.setOptions({
                strokeWeight: 0,
                fillOpacity: 0.5
            });
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myCell, 'click', function (evt) {
            big_createInfoWindowCell(data, evt.latLng);
        });
    }

    addCellEvent(myCell);

    return myCell;
}

big_loadMapCells();
```

Comment: What is `new CELL();`?

Comment: It is explained in the comment :  `// create polygon using my own javascript, CELL object` - but off course makes it very hard to replicate :)

Comment: CELL is my function to create Polygon. Because of my polygon is in shape of arch triangular.

Comment: Do you know which polygon has events added? The last one in the loop or just random?

Comment: Also do you really want the `addCellEvent()` function in the `big_createCellPolygon()` one?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you set `pagingCount` to 1?